# Digest authentication in ASP.NET Core / Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, digest-authentication, kestrel-http-server

Is it possible to use [digest authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) in ASP.NET Core / Kestrel? If it is, how do I enable and use it?

I know that [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is not and will not be implemented because [it's considered insecure and slow](https://github.com/aspnet/Security#notes), but I can't find anything at all about digest.

I don't want to use IIS' authentication because I don't want to be tied to Windows accounts, I want use a custom credentials validation logic.

Answer (score 5):

The only implementation of digest auth currently available with Core is the one in IIS that's tied to integrated windows auth.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the answer. This code is working for me:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest;
binding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
binding.AllowCookies = false;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://website.domain/WebService.svc"));
var client = new MessageServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = "password";

var response = client.CallMethod();
```

Comment: How to use it in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score -4):

Few thing about Kestrel, WebListener servers and authentication

- Kestrel does not directly support Windows Auth
- you must use WebListener or IIS + Kestrel to achieve that
- you just need to add forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" in your web.config file - https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/blob/dev/samples/IISSample/web.config#L13
- WebListener exposes AuthenticationManager - that can be used to configure the server authentication

And example how you can allow anonymous users using WebListener:

```
builder.UseWebListener(options =>
{    
     options.Listener.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.AllowAnonymous;
});
```

Comment: I'm not asking for [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication), what I'm looking for is [digest access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication).